# VBA excel how to select specify cells to change the background color

Tags: excel, if-statement, colors, vba

i have a code written in VBA that will check the date and base on the it will fill the background  with the appropriate color.

i have cells (A to G ).

i want to check if G is empty if so i want to change the background color of the cells (A)(B)(D)(E)(F)(G) except the CELL (C.

## CODE:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long

For i = Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 'Range upto 5000, chnge this as per your requirment'

    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then
         Range("A" & i & ":G" & i).Interior.Color = xlNone

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) < 0 Then
             Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) = 0 Then
             Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) >= 1 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) <= 4 Then
              Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) >= 5 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) <= 10 Then
               Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbCyan

    Else
                Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

 End If

    ' your 2nd criteria to color the entire row if "F" is not empty
    If Trim(Range("G" & i).Value) <> "" Then
                       Range("A" & i & ":G" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15


  ElseIf Trim(Range("G" & i).Value) = "" Then
                       Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 189, 189)
                       Range("D" & i & ":G" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 189, 189)

 End If

Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you should write:

```
Trim(Range("G" & i).Value) = ""
```

In stead of `Trim(Range("G" & i).Value) == ""`

The `==` operator does not exist in VBA, there is only `=`.

The rest should work ok. To avoid syntax errors like this, start writing `Option Explicit` on the top of the module. It will tell you immediately after you run the program where the error is.

---

Following your coding style, this is how you exclude column `C`:

```
Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
Range("D" & i & ":F" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
```

Comment: @Dany7elo - change 15 to 1 in the second place you write 15, now the two actions are the same.

Comment: aslo if i change it  it will not solve my problem and will fill the the columns  i want to exclude the column c

Comment: i will edit my code in my question because now it works but without taking into consideration the first if statement

Comment: @Dany7elo - and before it was taking the first if statement?

Comment: yes it was working .
now it make all the rows that are empty to be colored